# Jasmine testing does not recognize URL changing

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

This is my `base.js`:

```
self.logout = function(callback) {
     $http.post("api/logout")
     .then(function(response) {
         $window.location.href = "/";
     }, function(response) {
         self.accessErrors(response.data);
         callback();
      });
 };
```

and this is my `test_base.js`:

```
it('logout() should POST to api/logout and redirect on success', function() {
    // I want to test if the logout(cb) function posts to api/logout and, on success, redirect to /
    $loc.path('/logout');
    mockBackend.expectPOST("api/logout").respond(204, {msg: 'No Content'});

    var cb = jasmine.createSpy('cb');
    BaseService.logout(cb);

    mockBackend.flush();
    expect($loc.path()).toEqual('/');
});
```

But I get an error when I test this. The error says:

```
Expected '/logout' to equal '/'.
```

Any idea why it doesn't catch that URL changed to '/' when this line was executed:

```
$window.location.href = "/";
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, that the $http.post jumps into the function with the window.location.href?

Try it with

```
$window.location.href = "#/";
```

Comment: yes i put a `console.log('here')` right before the `$window.location.href = "/";` and it does get logged. I'm thinking it has to do something with me using `$window` instead of `$location`. also, I want to redirect to '/' though, which is different than '#/' right? Doesn't placing a '#' in front of the URL add onto the URL instead of fully redirecting? Anyways though, I'll try the code you posted when i get to work.

Comment: It depends in which context you are.a '/' can be used by states, '#/' with direct urls (except you configured your app to work without #). You can also try $rootScope.$apply(function() {
        $location.path("/");
      });

Comment: I'm getting the same error (`Expected '/logout' to equal '/'`) even when I try switching it to `$window.location.href = "#/";`.

Answer (score 0):

Because in my logout function I am using `$window.location.path` to change the URL, I made this my `test_base.js`:

```
it('logout() should POST to api/logout and redirect on success', function() {
    // I want to test if the logout(cb) function posts to api/logout and, on success, redirect to /
    $window.location.href = '/logout';
    mockBackend.expectPOST("api/logout").respond(204, {msg: 'No Content'});

    var cb = jasmine.createSpy('cb');
    BaseService.logout(cb);

    mockBackend.flush();
    expect($window.locaiton.href).toEqual('/');
});
```